# Building Object That Can Use Other Add-on Methods - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How do I build a dynamic object that functions like below? I want to build it form sever sheets to keep my code length low per page.

There is a simple example of my original code:

```
var app = {
  tow: function () {
    return true;
  },
  one: function () {
    return this.tow();
  }
};

// app.one() => returns true
```

Comment: I just ran your first snippet and it worked just fine, what's the issue?

Comment: What if you do something like `app['one'] = function () { return two();};`?

Comment: When I test run it on the below `JSBIN` I get a console error `two is not defined`. https://jsbin.com/vureruziza/edit?js,console

Comment: Why not create a class ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: @Phil, I thought classes were only for ES6?

Comment: @xxSithRagexx and?

Comment: @Phil Is ES6 client side now?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Have a look at the 'Revealing Module Pattern' or [ES6 modules](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html)

Answer (score 2):

I found your issue so you can it's just you were calling it wrong.

```
var app = {};

app.one = function () {
  return app.two();
};

app.two = function () {
  return true;
};

console.log(app.one());
console.log(app.two());
```

Comment: So app must always be called before the function? Is there a way without using app? What if I wanted to change the name of the var app?

Comment: you would have to make a `Builder` design pattern around the functions tying in to the app.